# Printing list items along with index

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list a = [x, y, z], and I want to print 


1. x

2. y

3. z

I can do it, but it is a bit lengthy, like

```
c = 1
for i in a:
     print(str(c) + "." + i)
     c += 1
```

Is there a shorter way of doing it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this example, where `i` is the `index` and `e` would be each item from `a` list.

```
for i,e in enumerate(a):
    print (str(i + 1) + '.', e)
```

As @niemmi suggests, you could also start the index at 1:

```
for i,e in enumerate(a, start=1):
    print (str(i) + '.', e)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was just looking for. :)

Comment: Instead of doing `i + 1` you could pass a starting index for `enumerate` as a second argument.

Comment: @niemmi Like this `enumerate(a, start = 1):` ?

Comment: @Apy That will work but there's no need to specify the parameter name; `enumerate(a, 1)` would do the same.